# Get partially matched string in an inner list (array property) of an indexed document in Elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, python, regex, elasticsearch

Suppose I have documents indexed in elasticsearch, where each document contains a field `names` which is an array of strings. 
When I search for a name say `abcd`, all documents where their `names` field partially contains searched string returns.

What I want is that, rather getting whole document that has its `names` field contains searched string, return `the string` or `entry` from `names` field, which matched partially to our searched string.

Suppose `names` field of few indexed documents are as follows:

```
names = ['1234', 'bcd', 'acd', 'abc'], doc_id = 1
names = ['abcd', 'ab'], doc_id = 2
```

if we search for string `abcd` then expected `outcome` is

```
{names: ['abcd', 'abc', 'ab']}
```

Comment: Using Aggregations in elasticsearch your problem will be solve.

Comment: @UttamPanara Can you suggest me elasticsearch query for the same? Though i've used `highlighting` feature of elasticsearch. Here is the link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html

Comment: I do not think it is possible to get exactly what you want. I think highlighting is the only option with [edge ngram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html)

Comment: @ChintanShah25, Yes I'm using `highlighting` and `edge-ngram` tokenizer to get similar result as above. Thanks to respond.